# Hot reloading with react-native and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've been able to get hot reloading to work in my React Native app with TypeScript, but it takes a bit of gymnastics. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it, or if this is just a limitation of TypeScript or maybe something I'm just not understanding.

```
// index.js
import 'src/App';

// src/App.ts
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from 'src/HomeScreen';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Homer', () => HomeScreen);

// src/HomeScreen.js
// It seems like this has to be a JavaScript file
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from 'src/Home';

// This must be a Component class. The class name is required. SFC does not work.
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Hello />;
  }
}
```

`src/Home.tsx` is the "normal" screen component that displays stuff. Even just `render() { return <Text>hello</Text>; }`.

My setup works and hot reloads, but for any screen-level TypeScript component I have to have this `...Screen.js` bridge file that wraps it.

Is there a way to have React Native hot reload the TypeScript module changes without the additional JavaScript wrapper?

I'm using https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer as the transformer for the TypeScript files with react-native.

Comment: So to be clear, you have to have a JS wrapper for any TS classes you use in order to get hot reload working?

Comment: @Emlyn yes, although the comments here https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer/issues/66 may help with hot reloading in some situations